# Vega viz truncated on grow

Tags: altair, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed

My web app has a vega-lite chart (from altair) with some `transform_filter`.

The issue is that the visualization doesn't grow when initial filters are removed. Because of this the visualization is truncated, neither don't scroll bars appear:

[image: this is a gif of char growing when filters are removed]

Char is embedded via `vegaEmbed`:

```html
<div id="view"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    embed_opt = {"mode": "vega-lite", "actions": false}

    var chart = {
       "config": {
         "view": {
           "continuousWidth": 400,
           "continuousHeight": 300
         }
       },
       ... }

    vegaEmbed(
        '#view',
        chart,
        embed_opt
    )                   
</script>
```

My question is:

How can I do to allow char to grow down freely? (scrollbars can also be a solution)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Altair, you can specify `.configure(autosize=alt.AutoSizeParams(resize=True))` to dynamically resize charts ([originally mentioned here](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2512)).